# Bot on Facebook Messenger does not receive the name of the users

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework

**In Microsoft Bot Framework V4, C#**
It only receives an empty string on dialogContext.Context.Activity.From.Name, except when the user has a role (Admin, Developer, Tester...) on the Facebook App. The app is approved and the bot is working.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I request **Business Asset User Profile Access** permission it works again. Maybe it is a bug
[image: Permission]